# Matlab code performace calculation. How to disable multiple cores on PC to assess performance of code

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, multicore, toolkit

I am running a code on MATLAB. I'm using Parallel Computing Toolkit. I make use of SPMD. I I have 8 cores on my PC. I want to run my code first on 1 core, see the time and then run my code on 2 cores and see the time, and so on.
 How can I disable/enable some cores of my machine?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The command `maxNumCompThreads` returns the maximum number of computational threads that the copy of MATLAB executing the command might use. However, MATLAB workers, as created by `matlabpool`, are single-threaded by design. Try this to confirm:

```
matlabpool open 2
parfor i = 1:2
    warning('off','MATLAB:maxNumCompThreads:Deprecated')
    maxNumCompThreads
    warning('on','MATLAB:maxNumCompThreads:Deprecated')
end
ans =
     1
ans =
     1
```

If you want to time your code while running on an increasing number of cores, try something like:

```
matlabpool open 1
runmycode
matlabpool close
matlabpool open 2
runmycode
matlabpool close
matlabpool open 3
runmycode
```

etc. up to `matlabpool open 8`.

Comment: Or, with R2011b, `matlabpool open 12`.

Comment: Although you can go up to 12 workers with R2011b, I did mean to stop at 8, as the OP mentioned he has 8 cores, More workers than cores is possible but unusual.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

`maxNumCompThreads(1)`

It's deprectaed, but works fine one all matlab I tested untill matlab 2011a.

Comment: Works on MATLAB R2015a as well.